# How do I reset hard drive in order to install Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, hard-drive

I encrypted my whole hard disk while installing Ubuntu 16.04, wich seemed to be a mistake, as now I cant create or modify any partitions.

Then, I'd like to reset the hard disk, back up already done, to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. I think its better to install Windows first, because from there installing Ubuntu is quite simple, not like the other way around.

My question then is, how do I reset my hard disk in order to be able to install Windows, and later on, Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete everything on the hard disk and prepare your system for a dual boot insert the live usb/dvd you made when installing Ubuntu and install and start gparted with ...

```
sudo apt install gparted
gparted
```

or create a [gparted live session](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) to do this.

Pick you disk(s), remove all partitions so it shows unallocated and then start dividing up the disk(s) into parts you feel comfortable with. I would suggest:

1. 1st partition for C: for your system. Yours to decide the size.
2. 2nd partition for D: for your personal data. Same comment.
3. any other partitions you want for Windows (boot/uefi partition?). Same comment.
4. partition for Ubuntu's root (`/`). At least 25Gb.
5. partition for Ubuntu's home (`/home/`). At least 10Gb if you want a data partition otherwise as large as possible
6. partition for your data (`/discworld/` is the name of mine) with the remainder of the hard disk.

---

From comment by [wjandrea](https://askubuntu.com/users/301745/wjandrea):

It might be better to erase the disk, install Windows, then do the manual partitioning to install Ubuntu, because in my experience, Windows creates its own partitions and doesn't give you any choice

---

The setup for Ubuntu lets you install a new version of Ubuntu with all settings reset by formatting and mounting `/` and `/home/` and simply mounting `/discworld/`. Or the same but by mounting (and not formatting) /home/ where you keep your settings. And a backup is backing up `/discworld/`.

When Ubuntu is done edit `.config/users-dirs.dirs` and change it so it points to `/discworld/` and delete the directories in `/home/$USER/`.

Then boot from the Windows installation media and install Windows with partitions 1, 2 and 3; leave 4, 5, 6 untouched. And after that is done install Ubuntu in partitions 4, 5, 6.

And to add: don't mount C: in Ubuntu (since it is a system disk I would always leave it as is); stick to D: for copying files from/to Windows.

Comment: It might be better to erase the disk, install Windows, then do the manual partitioning to install Ubuntu, because in my experience, Windows creates its own partitions and doesn't give you any choice

Comment: @wjandrea aha :D where there is shows my lack of windows experience ;-) There have a reward >:D

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it as well, @wjandrea . Still thanks a lot Rinzwind !